# Clickonce Publish Location

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to figure out how to make the Publishing Folder Location http for a Clickonce web deployment. I get "Publishing to an http endpoint from Visual Studio isn't supported, use an FTP endpoint instead". Is there a way around this?